# Can't detect collision between rootNode and pointOfView child nodes in SceneKit / ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, collision-detection, scenekit, arkit

In an AR app, I want to detect collisions between the user walking around and the walls of an AR node that I construct.  In order to do that, I create an invisible cylinder right in front of the user and set it all up to detect collisions.

The walls are all part of a node which is a child of `sceneView.scene.rootNode`.
The cylinder, I want it to be a child of `sceneView.pointOfView` so that it would always follow the camera.
However, when I do so, no collisions are detected.

I know that I set it all up correctly, because if instead I set the cylinder node as a child of `sceneView.scene.rootNode` as well, I do get collisions correctly.  In that case, I continuously move that cylinder node to always be in front of the camera in a `renderer(updateAtTime ...)` function.  So I do have a workaround, but I'd prefer it to be a child of pointOfView.

Is it impossible to detect collisions if nodes are children of different root nodes?
Or maybe I'm missing something in my code?
The `contactDelegate` is set like that:
`sceneView.scene.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` so maybe this only includes `sceneView.scene`, but will exclude `sceneView.pointOfView`???
Is that the issue?

Here's what I do:

I have a separate file to create and configure my cylinder node which I call `pov`:

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit


func createPOV() -> SCNNode {
    
    let pov = SCNNode()
    pov.geometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.1, height: 4)
    pov.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
    pov.opacity = 0.3    // will be set to 0 when it'll work correctly
    
    pov.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: nil)
    pov.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
    pov.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    
    pov.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.cameraCategory.rawValue
    pov.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue
    pov.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue
    
    pov.simdPosition = simd_float3(0, -1.5, -0.3)   // this position only makes sense when setting as a child of pointOfView, otherwise the position will always be changed by renderer
    
    return pov
    
}
```

Now in my `viewController.swift` file I call this function and set is as a child of either root nodes:

```
pov = createPOV()
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(pov!)
```

(Don't worry right now about not checking and unwrapping).
The above does **not** detect collisions.
But if instead I add it like so:

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pov!)
```

then collisions are detected just fine.

But then I need to always move this cylinder to be in front of the camera and I do it like that:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else {return}
        let currentPosition = pointOfView.simdPosition
        let currentTransform = pointOfView.simdTransform
        let orientation = SCNVector3(-currentTransform.columns.2.x, -currentTransform.columns.2.y, -currentTransform.columns.2.z)
        let currentPositionOfCamera = orientation + SCNVector3(currentPosition)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pov?.position = currentPositionOfCamera
        }
}
```

For completeness, here's the code I use to configure the node of walls in ViewController (they're built elsewhere in another function):

```
        node?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: node!, options: nil))
        node?.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        node?.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        node?.physicsBody?.damping = 1.0            // remove linear velocity, needed to stop moving after collision
        node?.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1.0     // remove angular velocity, needed to stop rotating after collision
        node?.physicsBody?.velocityFactor = SCNVector3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)           // will allow movement only in X and Z coordinates
        node?.physicsBody?.angularVelocityFactor = SCNVector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)    // will allow rotation only around Y axis

        node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue
        node?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.cameraCategory.rawValue
        node?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.cameraCategory.rawValue
```

And here's my `physycsWorld(didBegin contact)` code:

```
    func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
        
        if contact.nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue || contact.nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue {
            print("Begin COLLISION")           
            contactBeginLabel.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

So I print something to the console and I also turn on a label on the view so I'll see that collision was detected (and the walls indeed move as a whole when it works).

So Again, it all works fine when the `pov` node is a child of `sceneView.scene.rootNode`, but not if it's a child of `sceneView.pointOfView`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of collision detection?

Is there something else I can do to make this work, besides the workaround I already implemented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the positioning of your cyliner:

instead to use the render update at time, you better use a position constraint for your cylinder node to move with the point of view. the result will be the same, as if it were a child of the point of view, but collisions will be detected, because you add it to the main rootnode scenegraph.

```
let constraint = SCNReplicatorConstraint(target: pointOfView) // must be a node
constraint.positionOffset           = positionOffset // some SCNVector3
constraint.replicatesOrientation    = false
constraint.replicatesScale          = false
constraint.replicatesPosition       = true

cylinder.constraints = [constraint]
```

There is also an influence factor you can configure. By default the influence is 100%, the position will immediatly follow.

Comment: thanks so much for this suggestion! I didn't know about the replicator constraint. The effect is exactly the same and you're probably right that's it's better than using in the renderer function.
So I guess indeed children of different "root" nodes cannot collide ...

Comment: You are welcome. In fact, I never had a case, where I had to detect the collision between two objects that are not in the same scenegraph. It probably is exactly as you mention - I never tested this out in detail. Thanks for the Up-Vote!