# Sometimes after a collision clearly ends, didBegin contact is called last, AFTER didEnd contact - iOS / SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, collision-detection, scenekit

I have 2 nodes properly colliding with each other.
One node is a set of walls and is set as dynamic.
The other node is a cylinder which follows the camera in an AR view and is set as kinematic.
This is using ARKit, but the collisions are between SceneKit nodes.

The collision works exactly as I want it to and the walls' node moves correctly when the cylinder collides with it.

The problem is that I need to run some code when the collision ended to re-enable a button.

In `didBegin contact` I hide the button as such:

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    
    if contact.nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue || contact.nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == BodyType.wallsCategory.rawValue {
        
        freezeButton.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Then in `didEnd contact` I re-enable the button like that:

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didEnd contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    
    freezeButton.isHidden = false
}
```

And usually all of this works exactly as I wanted so the button correctly vanishes when a collision occurs and the button comes back when the collision ends.

BUT, often when the collision completes, the button does **not** return.

I added print statements in `didBegin` and `didEnd` and I also added similar labels on screen so I could clearly see when those functions are called.  What I see is that often the last call was to `didBegin` even after the collision has clearly ended.
I know this because I have `SCNDebugOptions.showPhysicsShapes` as debugOptions so I can clearly see that the cylinder is not touching the walls at all.

I then need to cause a new collision then walk back to have the `didEnd` function be called and get my button back.

I'm not using the `didUpdate contact` call as I don't need it.

How come `didBegin` is called last when clearly the collision has ended?
What could cause this to happen like that?

And what could I do to fix this?

I am thinking of a workaround which would check if some time has passed since the last `didBegin` that would indicate this is an old collision.
Or is there something else I could check if a collision is currently still in progress?  AFAIK, SceneKit doesn't have a function similar to `allContactedBodies` as in SpriteKit.
Is there something else I could use to check that 2 bodies are still in contact or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could probably give the End-Contact statement `freezeButton.isHidden = false` a small delay like with the `DispatchQueue`. This will re-enable the button on the next Run-Loop. This might not be the perfect solution, but it could give you better results than now. Give it a try.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.freezeButton.isHidden = false }
```

In addition you could check within the Begin-Contact if the Button is not hidden already, and only hide it if needed.

```
if !freezeButton.isHidden { freezeButton.isHidden = true }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately that didn't solve the issue.
After making your suggested changes and running the app, I got some backtrace in the console window and a purple warning  in the begin contact function saying ``UIView.isHidden must be used from the main thread only.``
So I put that code in a DispatchQueue closure as well and the warning disappeared. Running with the device hooked up looked promising, but further trials showed no improvement at all.
I just wonder what's the reason it's behaving like this. Maybe if I knew why, I could fix this for good. Thanks!

Comment: I also wonder, how it is possible that you get a did begin contact after the end contact. I am using probably similar functionality as well, and the did end always terminates sucessfully without strange did begin contacts afterwards. Sorry, I currently have no explanation for you issue. (if you copy your code into a totally new fresh project, does it behave the same way?) - could you share your code?

Comment: ZAY, thanks. You can see more of the relevant code in another related question I asked here: [Can't detect collision between rootNode and pointOfView child nodes in SceneKit / ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425840/cant-detect-collision-between-rootnode-and-pointofview-child-nodes-in-scenekit).